# Kodi not updating video tags correctly

Tags: video, kodi

I'm using Kodi 14.2 Helix and also using tinymediamanager to manage my library. I'm adding tags to some movies and tv-shows to be able to filter some lists.

NFO files seem correct, they have the  entries but Kodi does not generate them on the library.

Is there a way to force update reading tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can try going into <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Video</kbd> > <kbd>Clean Library..</kbd> which is visible when you change the settings view made to a level higher than standard (don't remember the exact minimum level).

Then rescan library either by enabling <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Video</kbd> > <kbd>Update Library on Startup</kbd> or by navigating to the folder in files and doing <kbd>C</kbd> > <kbd>Scan for New Content</kbd>.

*Also be sure to verify the content type is set (TV/Movies) and the scraper settings are configured as desired.*

If that doesn't work it may mean the naming scheme will need to be updated to a model with `S01E02` or a form of that. If that still doesn't work, you'll need to add custom regex formulas in `advancedsettings.xml` to pick up the details necessary for Kodi to recognize the content.

Kodi can be fairly picky with weirdly named files. See http://kodi.wiki/view/Naming_video_files/TV_shows for more details.

Personally I've had no luck with using NFO's for detection but see http://kodi.wiki/view/NFO_files for more details.

> Create a text file with a text editor (e.g. notepad) with exactly the
>   same name as the movie file (if all movies in one dir; in case each
>   movie has its own folder, place the .nfo file there and the name does
>   not matter). The extension has to be .nfo (e.g. Hellboy (2004)
>   English.DTS.1080p.x264.nfo).